# Identify line segments in a simple image

Tags: algorithm, line

I have an image that looks like the following. The image contains line segments. I want an algorithm to identify `k` number of line segments (that look like the ones inside the red rectangles). The number `k` is specified by the user. Is there any algorithm for this task?

[image]

Comment: why are some lines in boxes and not others? how are the "good" lines different from the "bad" ones?

Comment: They are all good. I put some of them in boxes just for illustration.

Comment: you should add `image-processing` tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your lines are well-formed. So consider using of [Hough line detecting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

It's implementation is available in [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) and another image processing libraries

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in ImageMagick using connected components to find each isolated white region after thresholding.

Input:

[image]

Threshold:

```
convert img.png -threshold 20% img_thresh.png
```

[image]

In ImageMagick, you can list out all the connected regions and get a number of statistics including their area. The list is ordered largest region first:

```
convert img_thresh.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null:


Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 832x984+0+0 415.3,492.2 813177 gray(0)
  2: 6x183+546+98 548.5,189.0 1098 gray(255)
  7: 6x181+546+292 548.5,382.2 1083 gray(255)
  17: 6x156+150+668 152.3,738.5 843 gray(255)
  8: 6x126+546+479 548.7,535.2 670 gray(255)
  6: 6x134+429+287 432.5,348.5 479 gray(255)
  1: 6x72+432+95 434.4,128.8 411 gray(255)
  4: 6x90+432+191 433.9,232.0 384 gray(255)
  9: 3x108+357+506 358.0,558.8 320 gray(255)
  5: 3x40+342+208 343.0,227.5 120 gray(255)
  11: 6x18+453+551 456.1,558.6 80 gray(255)
  13: 3x6+456+575 457.1,577.2 16 gray(255)
  3: 2x1+435+159 435.5,159.0 2 gray(0)
  12: 1x1+454+555 454.0,555.0 1 gray(0)
  14: 1x1+547+575 547.0,575.0 1 gray(0)
  15: 1x1+548+576 548.0,576.0 1 gray(0)
  16: 1x1+359+613 359.0,613.0 1 gray(255)
  10: 1x1+454+551 454.0,551.0 1 gray(255)
```

So we set the number k=5, for example and then extract the area of the 5th largest white region.

```
k=5
area=`convert img_thresh.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $4}' | head -n 5 | tail -n 1`
echo "$area
479
```

Then we process again telling connected components to discard all regions smaller than area=479. We use that as a mask to keep only the 5 corresponding regions from the input

```
convert img.png \
\( x2.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=$area \
-connected-components 4 \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
-background black -compose over -flatten \
result.png
```

[image]

So we see that now only the largest 5 regions are left in the image.

With OpenCV, you can use contours or blobs and likely do something similar.